# Python - removing some punctuation from text

Tags: python

I want Python to remove only some punctuation from a string, let's say I want to remove all the punctuation except '@'

```
import string
remove = dict.fromkeys(map(ord, '\n ' + string.punctuation))
sample = 'The quick brown fox, like, totally jumped, @man!'
sample.translate(remove)
```

Here the output is

```
The quick brown fox like totally jumped man
```

But what I want is something like this

```
The quick brown fox like totally jumped @man
```

Is there a way to selectively remove punctuation from a text leaving out the punctuation that we want in the text intact?

Comment: I'm not seeing any spaces in the output of this code. Are you sure that's exactly what you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the character you don't want to touch from the replacement string:

```
import string
remove = dict.fromkeys(map(ord, '\n' + string.punctuation.replace('@','')))
sample = 'The quick brown fox, like, totally jumped, @man!'
sample.translate(remove)
```

Also note that I changed `'\n '` to `'\n'`, as the former will remove spaces from your string.

Result:

```
The quick brown fox like totally jumped @man
```

Answer (score 4):

[str.punctuation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.punctuation) contains all the punctuations. Remove `@` from it. Then replace with `''` whenever you get that punctuation string.

```
>>> import re
>>> a = string.punctuation.replace('@','')
>>> re.sub(r'[{}]'.format(a),'','The quick brown fox, like, totally jumped, @man!')
'The quick brown fox like totally jumped @man'
```

Comment: what's the use of the regex part?